# Indentation on multi-line conditions

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

If we write long `if`-conditions in objective-c, we do the following (we try to stay below 100 or 120 chars per line):

```
if (   foo
    && [foo bar]
    && [[foo bar] isKindOfClass:[something class]])
    {
        [foo something]; ...
    }
```

Meaning: we align all conditions so that the first condition does have two spaces, because of the 'missing' operators.
Is it possible to align this in Uncrustify with objective c? I cannot find out how...

Comment: Of course in the example the first two conditions are not necessary due to how sending a message to nil works in Objective-C.

Comment: Try to align in xcode?

Comment: @Zaph, yeah, i know. I was just making something up to get an easy example. Just imagine there is more than one condition and an operator in between them.